# Dotnet docker container

Tags: .net, docker

I created a Default Web Api project (Weatherforecast) and without touching it I added Docker support. After that, I built the image by clicking over the docker file (on Visual Studio 2022) and selected Build Docker Image.
The default project, as you all know, it runs and works fine on localhost.
Now, I close Visual Studio and run the image like so:

`docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name somename myimage`

The container run and seems to open port 8080, at least is what it says in Docker Desktop, but the server is not running. if I try the following address:

`http://localhost:8080/swagger/index.html`

I get nothing on the browser.

If I run the project from inside Visual Studio with Docker, it works fine.
It is driving me crazy. Any ideas on how to properly run a dotnet docker image?

By the way, once that I have the container running (not the web api project) if I go inside the container and manually run `dotnet myimage.dll` it says something about the address: http://*:80 has been taken...

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Swagger is only enabled when the application is running in the development environment. By default, .NET docker containers run in production environment, so Swagger isn't available.

A quick fix is to set the environment when you run the container, like this

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name somename -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development myimage
```

For a more permanent solution, you can add

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

to your Dockerfile, either in the 'base' or the 'final' section so it ends up in the final image.